# Can please someone Explain this code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made a connection String in VB 2010 and is very easy to understand but i cannot figure out whats going on inside.

```
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender,System::EventArgs^  e) {

MySqlConnection^ con =gcnew MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=themohal123;database=myfirstdb");
        try
         {
             con->Open();
             MessageBox::Show("Connection Successful");
             con->Close();


        }
        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
         MessageBox::Show("Connection Not Successful"+ ex);
        }


         }
```

Comment: For starters, it is not VB code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not vb , it checks mysql connection status. You can work with this good if you wanna start vb.net.You give string query it returns datatable result

```
Public Function mysql(ByVal str_query As String) As DataTable
  Dim adptr As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim filltab As New DataTable
    Try
        Using cnn As New MySqlConnection("server=" & mysql_server & ";user=" & mysql_user & ";password=" & mysql_password & ";database=" & mysql_database & ";Allow User Variables=True")
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(str_query, cnn)
                cnn.Open()
                               adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                adptr.Fill(filltab)
                cnn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
```

'you can log mysql errors into a file here log(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Return filltab
    End Function